# Confusion b/w metro and desktop apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8

I have downloaded Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8. I think that to create desktop (non-metro) apps we need Visual Studio for Windows Desktop.

Am I right or this an be done in what I have?

Comment: What happens if you click New Project and select Windows Forms Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to develop a **Windows Forms app** you'll need Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 can build only Windows Store applications.  To build a traditional Windows Desktop application you need Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop or one of the non-Express editions (Professional, Ultimate, etc) which can build any type of application (Windows Store, Desktop, Windows Phone and Web).

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products